# PHP https ssl SoapClient Error with Centos Upgrade

Tags: php, openssl, centos, redhat

I have a PHP script that pulls orders from ChannelAdvisor using the SoapClient and has worked perfect for the past year.  I upgraded our Centos 6 server and now the script does not work.  It looks like it may be an OpenSSL issue from what I have gathered on the Internet.  I moved the script to a server that I haven't upgraded yet and it works like a champ.  I have also noticed that I can no longer "wget" any HTTPS addresses without it erroring out.

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://api.channeladvisor.com/ChannelAdvisorAPI/v6/OrderService.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => true, 'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS, 'connection_timeout' => '2'));
```

This is error I am getting...

```
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://api.channeladvisor.com/ChannelAdvisorAPI/v6/OrderService.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "https://api.channeladvisor.com/ChannelAdvisorAPI/v6/OrderService.asmx?WSDL" in get-orders-test.php on line 9
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like its related to the version of OpenSSL being provided by Cent OS 6; or the program needs to be recompiled due to an OpenSSL version change.

Comment: That's what I thought.  I was hoping they would make a new release soon.  Thanks!